# Concatenate zipped values in Python

Tags: python

I am just starting learn python. 
Please advise how I can concatenate this.

```
a='abc'
b='123'
```

As output I want:

```
[(a1, b2, c3)]
```

I tried to use built in `zip()` function but result is `(a, 1), (a, 2), (a, 3)`

Comment: `print(["".join(i) for i in zip(a, b)])` ?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(a,b)))` would give you `['a1', 'b2', 'c3']`, which would be a start in the right direction

Comment: Is there a reason you want your output to be a tuple inside a list? Why not just a tuple, or just a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can directly addup two string together, therefore you can try：

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the values after `zip`:

```
a='abc'
b='123'

print([v1 + v2 for v1, v2 in zip(a, b)])
```

Prints:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `''.join` and map. Would come handy when you have to join more that 2 elements

```
>>> list(map(''.join, zip(a,b)))
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```